# How to create a CassandraTableScanJavaRDD without connecting to Cassandra?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to unit test my method which connects to Cassandra and executes a select statement. The returned CassandraTableScanJavaRDD is then converted to a dataframe and further processing is done.

For my unit test, I don't wish to use an embedded cassandra. I am trying to mock CassandraTableScanJavaRDD using mockito. But I am not able to put some dummy data in it. 
How do I create a CassandraTableScanJavaRDD instance and have store some data in it, without actually connecting to cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Spark Cassandra Connector Embedded](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/10_embedded.md) - for many test cases it should work, I think that only for Spark Streaming jobs it may need real Cassandra.

Setup depends on your package manager - for example, for SBT it will be:

```
"com.datastax.spark"  %% "spark-cassandra-connector-embedded" % {version}
```

Latest version is 2.4.0, but you may need to use another, depending on the version of Spark that you're using...